# ArcGIS Online secure service access- user roles

Tags: arcgis-online

I've added a secure map service to my organization's AGOL account. I was prompted to enter a username and password while adding the service, and did so, choosing to not require a log in each time. From this service, I've created a WebApp. I've added the App to a group.

As the administrator, I can successfully view this content on the WebApp. However, users in the group that do not have their roles set as "Administrator" cannot view this content. The basemap displays, but the content is nonexistent. If I, as the administrator, change a user's role to "Administrator", then the content is available to them. Any other role, however, does not display the content.

For good reason, I do not want to give a user Admin privileges. What role other than Admin will allow a user to view secure content? Or, is there a custom role I can create where I can allow access to secure services without granting Admin privileges?

Comment: Did you share the secure layer item to the same group or access level as the WebApp?

Comment: That was it; I had only shared the WebApp with the group, and not the layer item. Once I added the layer to the group, users could access the secure service via the WebApp. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As Russ asked in the comment above, it sounds like it could be that the content is only being shared to people with the same access level.

In addition, it is possible that the content is not being shared at all. Administrators are able to see content that is created by all users within the organization.

Creating a group and populating with all members that you would like to share the content with and then sharing the data with that group is likely the best route for you to go.

[See this AGOL help page on roles.](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/roles.htm)